# Cauchy sequence if two consecutive terms get closer

Tags: sequences-and-series, lp-spaces, infinity, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

A bounded sequence has the property that $\|a_{n+1}-a_n\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ in a Banach space. Now, here comes the question that whether such a sequence is Cauchy. if not, we can add the assumption that the sequence has some monotonic behavior.

Comment: No. take the sum of the first $N$ inverse of natural numbers as $a_N$

Comment: which is famously unbounded ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of monotonicity conditions are you thinking about? Are they with respect to some order relation on the space? Just to note, those conditions mentioned are insufficient for convergence. For example, define the sequence $$\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \ \text{ by }\ a_n = (\cos(\ln(n)), \sin(\ln(n))$$
This is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that fails to converge to a single value (it just continually traces around the unit circle), but we have $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_{n+1}-a_{n}| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{[\cos(\ln(n+1))-\cos(\ln(n))]^2 + [\sin(\ln(n+1))-\sin(\ln(n))]^2 } \\ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{2 - 2[\cos(\ln(n+1))\cos(\ln(n))+\sin(\ln(n+1))\sin(\ln(n))]} \\ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{2 -2\cos(\ln(n+1) - \ln(n))} \\ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{2 - 2\cos(\ln(\frac{n+1}{n}))} \\ = 0 $$ That is to say the tracing is being done increasingly slow, so the points get closer together, just not to any particular value.

Comment: Thanks for providing a good example. A simplest type of monotonicity can be $\|a_n\|$ being monotone in $\mathbb{R}$. Although, we might be able to have more complicated types of monotinicity in infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: No problem! The condition that $||a_n||$ be monotone is still not enough (unless you specify that $||a_n||$ decreases to zero). In my previous example the norms were all monotonically decreasing. Even if the norms were strictly decreasing this still tells you nothing. You could modify the example I provided to make it a spiral and draw the same conclusion. In general, it seems that norm constraints typically don't tell you much about the behavior of the sequence. This is only the case in $\mathbb{R}^1$ since the norm corresponds to an order relation on the space.